# C# check if fileDialog have selected file

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I searched on internet, but I can't find answer on my question. Im making program on C# and it's open dialog window, to select folder. If folder selected, everything Ok, but if I press cancel, I have error. Is there some bool, to check if file selected?

Comment: yes, the openFileDialog returns bool on ShowDialog() or in WPF bool? on ShowDialog

Answer (score 6):

When you call "ShowDialog" it returns a DialogResult

Simply check if it's ok or cancel

```
DialogResult result =myDialog.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
//OK
}
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
//User pressed cancel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    // a file was selected
}
else
{
    // no file was selected
}
```